# how to remove the anonymous nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

help please delete anonymous text nodes.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c53dh/)

html:

```
<div class="cell image_outer">
    <label class="label">Фото</label>
    <div class="box_common_outer">
        <div class="box_common">
            <div class="box_common_inner">
                <img src="/media/cache/61/ad/61ad85ae26431c6fa3de2438e73bd7d2.jpg" width="83" height="83">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    На данный момент: 
    <a href="/media/userprofile/path_glory_photo/n_2.jpg">userprofile/path_glory_photo/n_2.jpg</a> 
    <input id="path_glory_photo-clear_id" name="path_glory_photo-clear" type="checkbox"> 
    <label for="path_glory_photo-clear_id">Очистить</label>
    <br>
    Изменить: 
    <input id="id_path_glory_photo" name="path_glory_photo" type="file">
</div>
```

should be able to:

```
<div class="cell image_outer">
    <label class="label">Фото</label>
    <div class="box_common_outer">
        <div class="box_common">
            <div class="box_common_inner">
                <img src="/media/cache/61/ad/61ad85ae26431c6fa3de2438e73bd7d2.jpg" width="83" height="83">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <input id="path_glory_photo-clear_id" name="path_glory_photo-clear" type="checkbox"> 
    <label for="path_glory_photo-clear_id">Очистить</label>
    <input id="id_path_glory_photo" name="path_glory_photo" type="file">
</div>
```

my database operations:

```
var label = $('.image_outer .label');
var thumb = $('.image_outer box_common_outer');
var label2 = $('.image_outer label[for="path_glory_photo-clear_id"]');
var photo_input = $('#id_path_glory_photo');
var checkbox = $('#path_glory_photo-clear_id');

$('.image_outer').empty().append(label).append(thumb).append(label2).append(photo_input).append(checkbox);
```

resulting output: label, label2, photo_input, checkbox.

the problem is that there appears no thumb, no nested elements to it

Comment: could you please provide information on what you have tried. Ie the code you've written to solve the task that does not quite work and then explain what doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.empty()`. What you are doing is clearing the `'image_outer` deleting ALL elements inside it instead of just the text elements. You need to find the text elements and remove them...

http://jsfiddle.net/3SDGZ/1/

```
 $(".image_outer").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 3;
 }).remove();
```